# Migrating a Power BI Desktop file to Analysis Services

Tags: powerbi, ssas-tabular, azure-analysis-services

Is it possible to convert a .pbix file into a .bim file while preserving all the data connections and expressions / shared expressions?

I have a power bi file I’ve exported into a .pbit file then loaded into Tabular Editor and saved as a .bim file and then loading the .bim file into SSDT visual studio 2015. My compatibility level is 1400.

The problem is that when I am converting from .pbix into .pbit that I lose data connections and shared expressions. The data connections are saved as “mashup” connection strings inside the database which reference back to the instance of power bi desktop I had open

How can I have these data connections remain as Oracle or SQL server connections?

Answer (score 0):

You can import a .pbix file into [Azure Analysis Services](https://azure.microsoft.com/da-dk/blog/import-power-bi-desktop-files-into-azure-analysis-services/). At that point, it becomes a regular Tabular model that you can download as an SSDT project (including the Model.bim file). However, you'll have to pay for the Azure Analysis Services instance during this operation.

Other than that, I guess you could ask the author of Tabular Editor to provide this functionality.